# How to read passwords and notes from keychain on non-apple OS?

Tags: keychain, migration

I see one solution — install macOS on virtual machine and do the job in it, but installing macOS in a VM is a huge PITA, even if I find where to download the os distribution. So I am asking for better ways.

Do you know of any software which can read data from keychains and is not tied to macOS-specific functionality?

(I am asking because my MacBook™ died too early, and nobody can fix it where I live, and of course I decided to not buy anything from Apple ever again because this hardware quality is unacceptable. So I need some way to get my passwords and stuff from backups…)

P.S. Maybe it's not the most appropriate stackexchange site to ask this question, but I can't decide where is the best place, so I am sorry if it's misplaced.

Also, to be clear: I know the password of keychain so it's not about cracking, etc.

Answer (score 3):

According to some [sources](https://discussions.agilebits.com/discussion/49587/is-there-an-easy-way-to-import-all-my-keychain-items-into-1-password) another Mac or a VM running macOS/OS X is required to dump your macOS keychain.

You can then convert the data and import it in e.g. 1Password with a [perl script](https://support.1password.com/import/#other-programs-data-converters-).

---

If you have problems finding another Mac, send me your login.keychain from the backup and its password ;-).

Comment: I may be stupid because I bought a mac once, but not stupid enough to give up passwords ;D